# Problem downloading Ubuntu into Virtual box

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu through BitTorrent.  Then I downloaded Oracle VirtualBox.  I've found a few different guides online but it keeps failing.  I'm not understanding what to do with the iso file once I've downloaded it and saved into my downloads.  Can anyone give me some good advice?  I'm running Windows 10 on my laptop.

Comment: There are step-by-step guides around the internet, http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox for example.